# How much air pressure is needed to push liquid out of a tank

Tags: fluid-mechanics, compressed-air

I want to use compressed air to push diesel out of a 100 gallon rectangular tank for fueling equipment.  Tank is 24” tall with a 30’ 3/4” hose reel on top. Height of the nozzle would be 6’ ft from the bottom of the tank at the highest but usually 1-2 ft above the bottom of the tank.

Comment: you need to know - static pressure of the fuel at the bottom of the pickup at atmospheric pressure.  Pressure greater than this will make it flow out.  How fast it flows out is another question.  You need to research how to do this and come back with questions you have about it.

Comment: Once all the pipe in the hose reel is full of fuel the siphon effect should draw it out of the tank if the end of the pipe is low enough.